# Multiple classes in markup - will it slow down performance?

Tags: css

So I'm working on a site for a major hotel chain and in the css they have a preexisting class for every imaginable situation.

I'm editing a page, adding over 100

instances with the code:

```
<p class="pad-b10 pad-t15 margin-b5 border-bottom-black">
```

Which applies a 10px padding to the bottom, a 15px padding to the top, a 5px margin to the bottom and a black border underneath.

My question is, does it make more sense to create one class that has all of these parameters included? I don't see very many custom classes in the rest of the css.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say without measuring it, but if you have multiple elements with the same style I would certainly create a single CSS class for it, and not just for performance reasons. You're basically just shifting pre-CSS markup habits into CSS. Pretty pointless: you may as just well write a style attribute directly as what you're doing now.

Comment: Do you apply these 3 classes frequently in your page??

Comment: Yes there's at least 100 instances / page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mozilla's implementation (and probably others as well), for each element, the CSS engine searches through style rules to find a match. The engine evaluates each rule from right to left, starting from the rightmost selector (called the "key") and moving through each selector until it finds a match or discards the rule. (The "selector" is the document element to which the rule should apply.)

In this scenario its very much worthy to have single style element so that the browser need to search only one key(css class name) which inturn increases the performance.

Comment: But how much would it be slowed down? Is it significant?

Comment: @user834045: Modern browsers are very faster in parsing these days. Not to worry about the performance but to have a cleaner and maintainable code, grouping the styles under a class is perfect as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend cleaning up that CSS the way you describe—in more consolidated classes—without hesitation. That CSS you inherited seems terribly limiting. But I don’t think it would slow down the page as much as drive anyone debugging the mess nuts! Which is a valid concern.

EDIT: It’s also like to add that naming classes based on position & height (`pad-b10`, `pad-t15`, `margin-b5` & such) is basically as bad as hardcoding inline CSS. Rework the CSS so thinks make sense semantically. And there has to be a common pattern so adapt to that. But CSS like that makes me ill.

Comment: Thanks guys, seems pretty obvious, but as they're such a big client I started thinking maybe their programmer knew something I don't. I'll wait until day 2 to suggest they rewrite the style sheet.

Comment: yeah, the whole thing seemed very strange to me too, not sure why you need css if your going to add each style element to the tag in mark up.