# Do many class names of an HTML impact performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I'm adding many class names (6 or 7) to the HTML elements for the requirement of my client javascripts.  Some of them are real class names, but some of them are just indicators.  Does this impact my page performance?

Comment: As far as the `class` attribute is concerned, "real class names" and "indicators" are the same thing. No class name is more or less "real" than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically more html means slower. But not that much, not noticable. Each character you write is a byte more to download, so it takes a while before you notice some differences.

The main problem that could occur is your css growing because you denormalize, that will have a much bigger impact.

If you need better performance, optimise images, or stylesheets, or some javascript codes

Short answer: **No, this is does not change anything significant.**

Answer (score 2):

This is a legitimate question because there can be very valid CSS and HTML that have best nesting and separation in the CSS that result in multiple CSS classes per element, and as you say, if you have marker classes for JavaScript lookups that adds to the volume. I cannot find any good performance analysis, but it shouldn't be hard to test.

This [Multiple classes in markup - will it slow down performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534689/multiple-classes-in-markup-will-it-slow-down-performance) basically says more classes = slower, but I don't know if that's true if each class has smaller content due to neater nesting in the hierarchy and better separation.

This http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/ is somewhat related and shows that complex CSS of well known sites is rendered efficiently.

My answer is that from personal experience I have not noticed performance issues with this design pattern so if your structure is best served by multiple CSS classes and marker classes then that is the most important aspect and performance should not suffer.